# How to make Android share Ubuntu's proxy?

Tags: networking, android, proxy, adb

I had make my android mobile connect to ubuntu using reverse tethering mode according to this link forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2287494.

below is my script, and works well.

```
▶ cat bin/reverse-tethering.bash 
#!/bin/bash

adb root
adb shell busybox ifconfig
adb shell netcfg rndis0 dhcp
adb shell ifconfig rndis0 10.42.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
adb shell route add default gw 10.42.0.1 dev rndis0
```

I setup global proxy in ubuntu, but the mobile seems not use the proxy setting. for the mobile can not connect to twitter, otherwise ubuntu can.

below is my setting, I use ssh -D socks:

```
▶ env|grep proxy
  28   :NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
  40   :all_proxy=socks://127.0.0.1:7070/
  41   :ALL_PROXY=socks://127.0.0.1:7070/
  55   :UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1
  65   :no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1
```

Anyone knows how can i do? The better way i want is add some lines in my bash, eg： use netcfg/ifconfig setup proxy point to ubuntu' port like 7070.

Comment: Take a look at this question [Android SDK Manager Proxy Settings in LINUX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634202/android-sdk-manager-proxy-settings-in-linux)

Comment: I think this url you give is not fit my need.